# Get all users, only when they don't occur in another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables. One *user* table and one table in which *results* are placed of a certain test.

When a user takes a test his result and his user_id are placed in the *results* table. When a user never took a test then obviously his user_id won't be in the *results* table.

I need to get all the users that are NOT in the results table. Is there a way to do this in one query? (Entity Framework)

Getting all the users is easy. But now i need a way to link it to the *results* table to see which of the users i want in my result set.

```
(from u in entity.Users
[where not in results table..??]
select u);
```

Comment: How are the OBJECTS related? Is there a relation between them or are they two unrelated entities?

Comment: You will need to join the two tables on the foreign key to the primary key. Then you will need to look into doing left and right joins, as these will enable you to find the results where it occurs in one table and not in another.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes they are related. there is a column "fk_user_id" in the **Results** table. Which is a forgeign key to the **Users** table on pk_user_id.

Comment: I asked about the OBJECTS not the tables. EF is an ORM and any relationship should surface as a property on User or an intermediate class. If User has a User.Results property you could just check it's empty (extremely inefficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully working example, using mock objects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var usersTakenTest = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Jim", "Angel" };
            var allUsers = new List<string> { "Bob", "Jim", "Angel", "Mike", "JimBobHouse" };

            var users = from user in allUsers
                        join userTakenTest in usersTakenTest on user equals userTakenTest into tempUsers
                        from newUsers in tempUsers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUsers)
                        select user;

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This user has not taken their test: " + user);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

.DefaultIfEmpty() is what you are after - if it brings back an empty result you have an object in table A that does not show in table B.